# quote key overloaded in matlab for toolbar keyboard shortcut

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

I've encountered an issue in MATLAB where the quote key seem to work as some kind of a keyboard shortcut to buttons on the toolbar.

After pressing the quote key, there's a change to the toolbar menu (see below), and the keyboard is used for that menu until unless Esc or another quote is pressed.

[image: toolbar shortcut dropdown]

[image: toolbar shortcut dropdown]

I've tried going to Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, but when I press Quote key (') to look for the shortcut, it displays: "Alt Graph + Quote" and shows no results.

How can this be disabled?

My environment is Xubuntu 16.04. It's something that didn't occur in the beginning when matlab was installed.

Comment: That's usually what the `alt` key does. Could it be that you have set a wrong keyboard mapping in your system? Do other keys work as expected?

Comment: @LuisMendo, other keys work as expected. Only MATLAB is behaving that way.